# Array de objetos en php desde javascript

Tags: javascript, php

tengo este codigo donde envio un array con objetos a php desde javascript, pero no me funciona , hay alguna forma de trabajar con estos objetos dentro del array en php

```
 codigo en javascript:


 let data=[{"name":"nombre1"},{"name":"nombre2"}];
    xhr.open('POST','post.php',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("data="+JSON.stringify(data));
```

y los recibo en php asi :

```
$data=json_decode($_POST["data"]);
```

me gustaria sacar cada objeto del array y trabajar con ellos en php algo asi como con un foreach,lo intente pero me da error

```
foreach($data as $objeto){

aca es donde trabajaria con cada objeto

}
```

Comment: Hola andres, en el backend de tu archivo php no es necesario utilizar el `json_decode` con solo pasar el `$_POST` a tu foreach es suficiente, solamente asegura que si estas enviando la informacion en formato JSON con eso solo basa

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el encabezado por: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');` y pasa el dato de este modo: `xhr.send('data' : JSON.stringify(data));` En PHP pon un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.